# Get value of textfield relative to label using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield

I have this kind of `HTML` on my page and I want to get the text field value (using a reference to above text on label tag). I can't use classes or ids as both are dynamic and can't be that way. My `HTML` code is below :

```
<div class="field required">
    <label class="label" for="options_114_text">
        <span>Length</span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
       <input type="text" id="options_114_text" class="input-text product-custom-option" name="options[114]" data-selector="options[114]" value="" aria-required="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying code like this but have issue how to reference it?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery('.field > label > span:contains("Length")').length > 0) {
        //How i refrence length textfield not width one here.I need here  
        jQuery('#options_114_text').val();
    }

    if (jQuery('.field > label > span:contains("Width")').length > 0) {

    }
});
```

The HMTL code is rendering from PHP and can't be same ids for text fields. So that's why I am trying with reference to above text that will exist each time.

Comment: @AkhilAravind if it's a possible duplicate, please either comment a link to the duplicate or flag the question appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you selected the label, you can go for the parent div and find the input field in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('.field > label > span:contains("Length")').length > 0) {
            //How i refrence length textfield not width one here.I need here  
            var textfield = $('.field > label > span:contains("Length")').closest('.field').find('input');
            console.log(textfield.val());
        }
        if ($('.field > label > span:contains("Width")').length > 0) {

        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field required">
   <label class="label" for="options_114_text">
       <span>Length</span>
   </label>
   <div class="control">
       <input type="text" id="options_114_text" class="input-text product-custom-option" name="options[114]" data-selector="options[114]" value="test" aria-required="true">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I like it due to short and easy one.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```js
function get_val(_span_text){
  var out=null;
  $('.field').each(function(){
 var span_text=$(this).find('label').find('span').text();
 var input_val=$(this).find('div').find('input').val();
     /* or  var input=$(this).find('div').find('input'); for DOM manipulation  */
 if(span_text==_span_text){
    out=input_val
  /* or out=input; for DOM manipulation */
 }
  });
  return out;
}

 console.log('Length=>'+get_val('Length'));
 console.log('Width=>'+get_val('Width'));
```

```css
       div{
         display:inline-block;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:gray;
         padding:10px;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div class="field required">
        <label class="label" for="options_114_text">
            <span>Length</span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="options_114_text" class="input-text product-custom-option" name="options[114]" data-selector="options[114]" value="12" aria-required="true">
        </div>
   </div>

   <div class="field required">
        <label class="label" for="options_114_text">
            <span>Width</span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="options_114_text" class="input-text product-custom-option" name="options[114]" data-selector="options[114]" value="18" aria-required="true">
        </div>
   </div>
```